# How to emulate multiple jq inputs while developing filters to seamlessly allow multiple files as inputs

Tags: jq

I am in the process of needing to pass the contents of 2 JSON files through a jq query. I wasn't exactly sure how to create the jq filter at first due to being uncertain how the input would look like. In fact, I was going to submit an issue to jq play to allow for multiple inputs, until I realized this might already be allowed.

So I made the decision that the input from different files would basically be JSON Lines (ndjson) input. Something like the following, which should emulate 2 JSON files, I believe.

```json
{
  KEY1: [VALUE1, VALUE2],
  KEY2: [VALUE3]
}
{
  KEY1: [VALUE4],
  KEY3: [VALUE5]
}
```

From there I started to build my jq filter (which assumes the above format). This filter correctly merges the two files together.

```
[inputs | to_entries | sort] | add
| map(.value[] + {"lineage": .key})
| group_by(.lineage) | add | unique | sort_by(.repo, .issue)
| group_by(.lineage)
| map({(.[].lineage) : [.[] | del(.lineage)]}) | add
```

Here is a more detail set of input: https://jqplay.org/s/Tle2W8PIgQj

Now, I am stuck figuring out whether I made the right assumption above and how to correctly input the 2 files into the jq command

There seem to be several different ways to do this, and so far all seem to fail for me. Here is the latest version I have tried (this is implemented within GitHub Actions)

```
jq --null-input --raw-inputs \
  <filter> \
  mappings.json ${owner}_${repository}.json |
  > merged.json
```

Both `mappings.json` and the file `${owner}_${repository}.json` have their content pretty printed in each file.

But I am getting the following error

```
jq: error (at mappings.json:1): string ("{") has no keys
```

When I look at the content of `mappings.json`, it is a valid json structure without additional quotes

So I am wondering what the correct way of inputting file content for use with the built-in `inputs`. And was I correct in my way of emulating 2 input files when building my jq filter? My current hypothesis is that my assumption was wrong, and that is why my actual jq command is erroring.

Comment: `--raw-inputs` reads each line of the inputs into _a string_! Why do you want to do that? If you have JSON files, you must (generally) read them as JSON

Comment: Oh wow, when I get back to my laptop I'll try this. I can't believe I figured out the filter to merge my json data, but failed this easily at the command options. I don't want to read them as strings

Comment: There is no `--raw-inputs` option, only `--raw-input`.

Comment: @ChristopherRucinski you can easily trigger the same error on jqplay too, by enabling "Raw Input": https://jqplay.org/s/I4Sc-UHQUGE

Comment: Thank you! My mistake. I fixed the raw-inputs issue already in my GitHub action workflow, but must have copy-pasted the wrong jq command here. When experimenting I tend to just copy the filter as everything else is formatted correctly in my workflow. I never had raw-input checked in jq play, so I must have experimented with raw-input directly in my workflow and forgot to remove it.`

Comment: I'm voting to close as "not reproducible or was caused by a typo"